# Can we use `data.table` syntax in preconditions of `pointblank` package?

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to use `data.table` syntax in `pointblank` preconditions?  Two reasons for this. First, I already had written some code checking my data before learning about `pointblank`, but all these tests were written in `data.table` syntax. With the preconditions argument, it would extremely easy to incorporate them into the whole data validation process. Second, when checking big data, being able to use data.table will highly speed up the process.

I tried something like the code below, but it failed with the following message, `Error in .(un = unique(survey_comparability)) :  could not find function "."`

```r
 col_vals_equal(vars(diff),
                 value = 1,
                 preconditions = ~.[, 
                                    .("un" = unique(survey_comparability)),
                                    by = .(country_code, survey_coverage)
                                   ][
                                     order(country_code, un)
                                   ][, 
                                     diff := un - shift(un), 
                                     by = .(country_code) 
                                   ][
                                     !is.na(diff)
                                   ]
  )
```

Thank you so much.
Best,

Comment: It appears you can't. It doesn't seem like [.data.table is called since it would substitute the dot with list before evaluation. But I don't know the pointblank package.

Comment: Can you use `.SD` in place of `.` in your `~`-function? (I also do not know `pointblank`.)

Comment: it appears with other `~`-honoring functions (e.g., `model.frame` and `purrr::map`), the use of `.SD` works when `.` does not. I suspect that the `.` use in `~` formulas/expressions is mostly a `tidyeval` thing, I'm not sure if `pointblank` subscribes to that flow. Either way, I think `.SD` might work for you.